# same Public IP is generated even after restarting gcp compute instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using free credits for GCP. I have created multiple instances of compute engines. To save the cost I stopped the instances. After starting again it should return another IP from the pool but the same IP is returned.
That's why I am unable to access my instance. Please advise me on it?

Comment: Why you can't connect on the same IP? Why is it a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to clarify something first: for [external IP Addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#externaladdresses) (sometimes called public IP) on a GCE instance, there are basically two options:

1) Static: Remain attached to instances until they are removed, it doesn't matter if the instance is stopped or restarted (you need to reserve it first)

2) Ephemeral: Remain attached to a VM instance only until the VM is stopped/restarted or the instance is terminated. When a stopped instance is started again, a new ephemeral external IP address is assigned to it.

If you want your instances to not preserve their IP addresses be sure that it doesn't have a Static IP assigned, you can list all of them on the GUI ([Main Menu - VPC Network - External IP Addresses](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses/list)) you will see all the IP being used and its associated resource, but this must not affect the way you access it (in fact, in most cases is desirable to have this configuration, for example, if you are automatically consuming a service from this instance you don't want to change the IP each time it is restarted).

If you are trying to access your instances via SSH or RDP, then check that your [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) are allowing incoming traffic to ports 22 or 3389 from Internet (0.0.0.0/0), on the [firewall rules section](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list) you should see something like this:

> default-allow-rdp | Ingress | Apply to all | IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 | tcp:3389
>
> default-allow-ssh | Ingress | Apply to all | IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 | tcp:22

by default GCE create these firewall rules, see this for more information on how to [access your instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance). If that's not the case, share more details about your issue.